# Property gets nilled

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, properties

I have an existing app, which ins on the app store since 2010. Because of a lack of free time, I could not update it from pre iOS7 to iOS7+ up to now. And this is what I am trying to do at the moment (with most recent 9.2 SDK).

However, I am having some weird problem, and I cannot even get close to some possible cause, and I'm pretty lost and don't know how to investigate further.

Upon start, the app loads an object from the core data storage, which is of class `YearSummary` (directly inherits `NSManagedObject`, and only has some simple attributes). This object gets saved in a `retain`-property of my root viewcontroller.
Now the weird thing is, that after the object was successfully loaded, the property somehow gets reset to `nil`, and the objects attributes cannot be displayed in my app by the root viewcontroller. I have no idea how this happens, and why this happens.

I already made this a non-property with my own setter, so I can track when it gets reset to nil, but without success. No obvious changes for the object could be found.

This, roughly, is my code: (the apps code is rather large, I try to find the important parts)

`rootviewcontroller.m`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    YearSummary* thisYear= [SomeClass fetchYear:2016];
    self.currentYear= thisYear;   // retain property

    NSLog(@"Loaded existing Summary (%p) for CURRENT year (%d)", thisYear, 2016);

    [self.tableView reloadData];  // will display stuff from current year in a tableview
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

`someclass.m`:

```
+(YearSummary*)fetchYear:(int)year
{
   NSManagedObjectContext* context= [ServiceClass getManagedObjectContext];

   if (!context)
      return false;

   NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YearSummary" inManagedObjectContext:context];
   NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"year == %d, year];
   NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"year" ascending:NO];
   NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

   [request setPredicate:predicate];
   [request setEntity:entity];
   [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
   [sortDescriptors release];
   [sortDescriptor release];

   NSError* error= nil;
   NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

   [request release];

   if (!results || ![results count])
   {
      [ServiceClass showErrorMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) withText:NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to load data from storage", nil) andError:error];
      return 0;
   }

   return [results objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Again `rootviewcontroller.m`:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
   NSLog(@"Tableview header with year year (%d) (%p)", self.currentYear.year.intValue, self.currentYear);

   if (self.currentYear)
      return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", NSLocalizedString(@"Overview", nil), [[self.currentYear year] intValue]];

   NSLog(@"DONT HAVE CURRENT YEAR");

   return @"";
}
```

This is going to print upon app start:

```
2016-01-03 14:51:39.410 MyApp[12103:655470] Loaded existing Summary (0x13f6e0f90) for CURRENT year (2016)
2016-01-03 14:51:40.394 MyApp[12103:655470] Tableview header with year year (2016) (0x13f6e0f90)
```

But the table header shows a nil-string as title, which confuses me, because according to the above code should **not** be possible??

When I drag the tableview, so the title gets re-created, this is printed:

```
2016-01-03 14:51:42.695 MyApp[12103:655470] Tableview header with year year (0) (0x0)
2016-01-03 14:54:13.089 MyApp[12103:655470] DONT HAVE CURRENT YEAR
```

Can someone guide me into a possible solution, or give me tips how I can trace down the root cause of this behaviour?

Note: Since this is an old app, I am not using ARC in my project.

[edit]
I also added a watchpoint, as suggested below. This is the output:

```
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 2: addr = 0x125740fa8 size = 8 state = enabled type = w
    watchpoint spec = 'currentYear'
    new value: 0x0000000000000000
```

... after a second or so:

```
Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 0x0000000000000000
new value: 0x000000013ccdcf90
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a *watchpoint* on the backing instance variable?  Also updating the ARC can be achieved and is worth the effort.

Comment: I added the watchpoint, see results above in edited post.

Comment: Check also the address of the controller printing the results, not just the results printed.

Comment: Following on from a previous comment, is it possible that you have two `rootviewcontroller` instances and one of them is never shown, therefore never calling `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: The important thing about the watchpoint is what's in the stacktrace (i.e. what is setting the property)?

Comment: Have you tried using KVO? Perhaps you could throw in an observer, set a breakpoint when the method is called that nils the object, and backtrace to see what happened?

Comment: @PhillipMills thanks a bunch, that indeed was the problem. When porting to  iOS 9 I messed around quite a bit with the main interface file, and indeed I ended up with 2 root view controllers. Now its fixed and works.
Add your hint as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

When an object's property has an unexpected value, especially one that appears to be uninitialized, check that the object is actually the one you expect it to be by logging the address or viewing it in the debugger.

(This is especially common with nil IBOutlets in a view controller.)